# subquery with aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I'm having hard time finding out how to get a project number or project name from a table where have the most employees

```
create table Pro_works_on
(
    EID char(9) ,
    PNO char(9) ,
    Pro_HOURS smallint not null,
    constraint pk_Pro_works_on primary key(EID,PNO),
);

SELECT
  p.PNO
FROM
  Pro_works_on AS p
 ,(
    SELECT
      COUNT(p.EID) AS numOfEmployee
     ,p.PNO
    FROM
      Pro_works_on AS p
    GROUP BY
      p.PNO
  ) AS L
WHERE
  MAX(L.numOfEmployee) = COUNT(p.EID);
```

It produces the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: What kind of SQL are you using? That error looks sort of like MS SQL Server, but I'm not certain.

Comment: or MySQL, or DB2.

Comment: microsoft SQL management studio

Comment: SQL is just a language used by many vendors.  Please be specific on your dbms.

Comment: It's called SQL Server, so add the tag to your question.  SQL Management Studio is just a GUI interface you use to interact with your database.

Comment: Have you tried to run your inner query, and see if it produce more than one row or not.  If yes, then that's the problem.

Comment: i have more than 1 row beacuas what if i have more the one project with max

Comment: In SSMS, run `SELECT @@Version`. That should tell you what version it is.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4293803) - 14.0.2002.14 (X64)   Jul 21 2018 07:47:45   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home 10.0 <X64>

Answer (score 2):

Use `order by` and some sort of limiting clause -- if you want one row.  In standard SQL:

```
select p.PNO, count(*) as numOfEmployee 
from Pro_works_on p
group by p.PNO
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

In SQL Server, you would use `top (1) or`top (1) with ties`:

```
select top (1) p.PNO, count(*) as numOfEmployee 
from Pro_works_on p
group by p.PNO
order by count(*) desc;
```

Comment: but it does not answer what i need. i need the project where the are the most of the employee . here its only give me the number of each project.

Comment: @MikaAzulay . . . Have you run this query?  It gives the project with the most employees.

Comment: For SQL Server, this would need `OFFSET 0 ROWS` before the `FETCH` statement.

Comment: RE: your edit: `OFFSET/FETCH` can be used in SQL Server as of SQL 2012, though I think it was more limited until later versions. It would offer some performance improvements over `TOP`. (And I don't think it can do `WITH TIES`, but it can be replicated).

Comment: @Shawn . . . Do you have a reference on performance improvements using `OFFSET/FETCH`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'll have to look for them. My quick, early-morning Google-fu is failing me. And the more I think about it, the performance differences may only really come into play when pagination is being performed, which we aren't doing here. So I may have to set up some test data to play with.

Answer (score 2):

for aggregated result you should use having for filter and not where

```
select L.PNO 
    from Pro_works_on p, (
    select count(p.EID) as numOfEmployee
    ,p.PNO
    from Pro_works_on p
    group by p.PNO) L
HAVING  MAX(L.numOfEmployee)=numOfEmployee
```

but could be you can use a more  simple way avoiding problem related to group by using an order by and limit 1

```
    select L.PNO 
    (
        select count(p.EID) as numOfEmployee
        , p.PNO
        from Pro_works_on p
        group by p.PNO
    ) L 
    order by numOfEmployee DESC 
    LIMIT 1
```

Comment: it says:  Column 'Pro_works_on.PNO' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: still: Column 'L.numOfEmployee' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

Break your problem down into steps.

First, you need to know how many employees are assigned to each project. That way you'll know which one has the most employees. To do that, use `COUNT` with `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT 
  p.PNO, COUNT(p.EID) AS numOfEmployee
FROM
  Pro_works_on AS p
GROUP BY
  p.PNO
```

Next, have your query put your results in the order you want them by using `ORDER BY`. You want the project with the most employees to come first, so put them in `DESC`ending order.

```
SELECT 
  p.PNO, COUNT(p.EID) AS numOfEmployee
FROM
  Pro_works_on AS p
GROUP BY
  p.PNO
ORDER BY COUNT(p.EID) DESC;
```

Finally, since you only care about the one project with the most employees, add a row limiter. In SQL Server, you do that with the `TOP (N)` expression. And since you only care about the project number, not the actual count of employees, you can take the `COUNT` out of the results, and just leave it in the `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES
  p.PNO
FROM
  Pro_works_on AS p
GROUP BY
  p.PNO
ORDER BY COUNT(p.EID) DESC;
```

**EDIT**: Added `WITH TIES` based on the OP's question in the comments.

Comment: if i have two or project which have the max number of employee?

Comment: An excellent question. I edited my answer, but you just have to change it to `TOP (1) WITH TIES`, and it will return as many projects as there are that have the max number of employees.

Comment: When you use `WITH TIES`, it returns all of the results that are tied for _last_ place, but since we're doing `TOP (1)`, first place is also last place, so it works for what you need.

Comment: @EricBrandt _last place_ with regards to your ordering. It can be mind bending to think about what it's doing. If you say return `TOP 3 WITH TIES` and there are 2 rows with 5 employees and 4 rows with 3 employees, it will return 6 rows because the 2 5-employees and 1 of the 3-employees are within the `TOP 3`, but the other 3 3-employees `TIE` with that last ranked one, and get included in the results. :-S

Comment: @Shawn, yup, it can get weird, and your example is spot on. On the other hand, for this sort of thing it's just the ticket. I use it all the time, usually with a `RANK() OVER` in the `ORDER BY` clause to get the newest/oldest/largest/smallest/whateverest x for each y. No need for that level of weirdness, though, for Mika's question.

Comment: @MikaAzulay, the code you come up with isn't really the thing here. All of the answers posted will, I think, get you your result set. I was more interested in walking you through the thought process to get from a blank screen to working code.

Comment: @EricBrandt Absolutely. And I'd honestly just never thought about the way it worked. It's great functionality.

Comment: ... This is definitely the cleanest way to get to the answer. With a lot of records, the `OFFSET/LIMIT` method might be more performant, but it would also require some SQL magic to get the `WITH TIES` records. Same with my `RANK()`ed sub-select. If performance is an issue, I think all 3 methods should be tested.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to return multiple Projects if they each have the highest number of employees, you can use a window function to aggregate and then filter by that.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT p.PNO
        , count(*) AS empCount
        , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY count(*) DESC) AS r
    FROM Pro_works_on p
    GROUP BY p.PNO
) s1
WHERE r = 1
```

That will rank all of them in order and set the rank of all of the highest employee counts to 1. Then just select all that have rank of 1.

Answer (score 0):

To get the project with the biggest number of employees I would do:

```
with
x as (
  select
    pno,
    count(eid) as tot_emp
  from pro_works_on
  group by pno
),
y as (
  select max(tot_emp) as max_emp from x
)
select 
  x.pno
from x
join y on y.max_emp = x.tot_emp
```